# Configuring TestContainers for Per-Test Database Containers in Integration Tests

Tags: c#, .net, testing, integration-testing, testcontainers

I'm attempting to set up integration tests for my Campaign repository and I'm encountering an issue with the TestContainers NuGet package. My goal is to have a separate database container created for each test. However, when I run the tests, it seems that the container is only created once and then disposed, instead of being created for each test.

Is there a way to configure TestContainers to create a new container for each test, or is there something specific I should check in my setup to ensure this behavior?

My code:
`PostgresFixture.cs`

```
namespace MyProject.Tests.IntegrationTests
{
    public sealed class PostgresFixture : IAsyncLifetime
    {
        public readonly PostgreSqlContainer PostgreSqlContainer = new PostgreSqlBuilder().Build();
        public Task InitializeAsync()
        {
            return PostgreSqlContainer.StartAsync();
        }

        public Task DisposeAsync()
        {
            return PostgreSqlContainer.DisposeAsync().AsTask();
        }

        public async Task ExecuteCmdAsync(string query)
        {
            using (DbConnection connection = new NpgsqlConnection(PostgreSqlContainer.GetConnectionString()))
            {
                using (DbCommand command = new NpgsqlCommand())
                {
                    connection.Open();
                    command.Connection = connection;
                    command.CommandText = query;

                    await command.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`CampaignRepositoryTests.cs`

```
namespace MyProject.Tests.IntegrationTests
{
    public class CampaignRepositoryTests : IClassFixture<PostgresFixture>
    {
        private readonly PostgresFixture _fixture;
        private readonly ICampaignsRepository _campaignsRepository;
        private readonly DbContextOptions<CampaignsDatabaseContext> options;
        private readonly CampaignsDatabaseContext _context;
       
        public CampaignRepositoryTests(
            PostgresFixture fixture)
        {
            _fixture = fixture;

            TestDomainEventBus DomainEventBus = new();
            TestIntegrationEventStoreDispatcher IntegrationEventStoreDispatcher = new();

            options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<CampaignsDatabaseContext>()
                .UseNpgsql(_fixture.PostgreSqlContainer.GetConnectionString())
                .Options;

            _context = new CampaignsDatabaseContext(options, DomainEventBus, IntegrationEventStoreDispatcher);

            _context.Database.Migrate();

            _campaignsRepository = new CampaignRepository(_context);

            SeedDatabase(@"TestData/campaigns_insert.sql").Wait();
        }

        private async Task SeedDatabase(string filename)
        {
            var sql = File.ReadAllText(filename);
            await _fixture.ExecuteCmdAsync(sql);
        }

        [Fact]
        public async Task Find_By_Id_Should_Return_Campaign()
        {
            var campaignId = await _campaignsRepository.FindById(Guid.Parse("47a3ff0b-98f9-45a8-a6e5-c6821d624775"));
        }
        [Fact]
        public async Task Find_By_Id_Should_Return_Campaign2()
        {
            var campaignId = await _campaignsRepository.FindById(Guid.Parse("47a3ff0b-98f9-45a8-a6e5-c6821d624776"));
        }
        [Fact]
        public async Task Find_By_Id_Should_Return_Campaign3()
        {
            var campaignId = await _campaignsRepository.FindById(Guid.Parse("47a3ff0b-98f9-45a8-a6e5-c6821d624777"));
        }
        [Fact]
        public async Task Find_By_Id_Should_Return_Campaign4()
        {
            var campaignId = await _campaignsRepository.FindById(Guid.Parse("61a83cfe-0e5c-49fc-988a-5b8fe6614673"));
        }
    }
    class TestDomainEventBus : IDomainEventBus
    {
        public Task Publish<TEvent>(TEvent @event, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default) where TEvent : IDomainEvent
        {
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    }
    class TestIntegrationEventStoreDispatcher : IIntegrationEventStoreDispatcher
    {
        public ValueTask Dispatch(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
        {
            return ValueTask.CompletedTask;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is because you are using a class fixture. Please read xUnit.net's [Shared Context](https://xunit.net/docs/shared-context) documentation.

Comment: Could you give your comment as an answer? It was what I need and I would like to give you thumb up